# Write a function that takes another function and an Int and applies it 3 times

Tags: haskell

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a  
twice f x = f (f x)
```

This function applies it twice, but I couldn't figure out how it can apply it 3 times. I tried:

```
threeTimes:: (a -> a) -> a -> a -> a  
threeTimes f x = f (f(fx))
```

and many other ways, but could't come up with a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `threeTimes:: (a -> a) -> a -> a`? Also, `f (f(fx))` is _not_ the same as `f (f(f x))` - the space matters here. I'm really unclear on what you are asking...

Comment: Likely you are just missing a space between `f` and `x`

Comment: Your `threeTimes` function takes 3 parameters according to the type signature, but you're only using 2 parameters.

Comment: so let's say I run the code with  twice (+2) 10  The output would be 14. It adds 2 to 10 twice. What I am trying to figure out is how would it apply it three times so that output would be 16 instead of 14

Comment: `applyNTimes n f x = iterate f x !! n`

Comment: @4castle or `applyNTimes n = appEndo . stimes n . Endo`.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems, one a simple typo, the other more conceptual.

The *type* of `threeTimes` is exactly the same as that of `twice`; you give it a function and an argument.

```
threeTimes :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

The body is fine; you simply forgot the space between `f` and `x`; `fx` is an undefined name.

```
threeTimes f x = f (f (f x))
```

The similarity between `twice` and `threeTimes` is even more apparent if you write them in point-free style (with a little more whitespace than is usual to emphasize the similar parts):

```
twice      f = f . f
threeTimes f = f . f . f
```

In fact, you could simply define `threeTimes f = f . twice f` (or `twice f . f`; the two are equivalent since composition is associative).

Comment: Thank you guys. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your space is getting in the way. Try this:

```
thrice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
thrice f x = f $ f $ f x
```

That's an equivalent statement to:

```
thrice' :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
thrice' f x = f (f (f x))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it now.